# How to show there is no real valued function whose limit approaches to infinity at every real number.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Question: **Show that** there is no function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that for every real number a, $f(x)$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches $a$.

We know that, limit of function $f$ as $x$ approaches to $a$ is infinity if for all $N>0$ there exist $\delta>0$  such that $f(x)>N$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

then by above we get $f(x)>m$ for every $m\in \mathbb{R}$ and hence such real valued function $f$ does not exist.

is this proof is correct? If not Please explain me what details are missing and what mistakes I had done in proof. Thank you.

Comment: @David Mitra sir please elaborate and then what's the right way to proceed

Comment: I don't see how you get your conclusion. Perhaps more detail is needed. (You need $0<|x-a|<\delta$ in the second sentence.)

Comment: Sir what more details are needed? and @RRL sir though this question was already answered. But as there are many ways to prove same result, so  here too there may be many ways to solve above question.